# select2 multiple with ajax data initializing with Undefined

Tags: jquery-select2

I followed the example provide in the docs, and applied it to a select multiple but some things don't work as expected.
Instead of getting the actual values I get Undefined, Undefined

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/orbitory/3e85rLue/) is the JSFiddle code with the problem

Am I missing a step?

This part of the example provided [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2) doesn't work for me. The console.log shows the correct data but select2 shows undefined in the select

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
    console.log(item);
    var option = new Option((item.name + ' (' + item.code + ')'), item.id, true, true);

    preRequisites.append(option).trigger('change');

  });

  preRequisites.trigger({
    type: 'select2:select',
    params: {
      data: data
    }
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the code needed this part **item.text ||**

```
templateSelection: function(item) {
    return item.text || (item.name + ' (' + item.code + ')');
},
```